# Why am I getting object has no attribute?

Tags: python, adapter, deque

I have written a code that uses python deque from collections. I have created an adapetr class `queue.py` that handles queue operations. But I am getting error object has no attribute.

`queue.py` :

```
from collections import deque


class Queue:
    def __int__(self):
        self._items = deque()

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self._items.append(item)

    def extend(self, *elements):
        self._items.extend(elements)

    def dequeue(self):
        try:
            return self._items.popleft()
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError("Dequeue from empty queue") from Queue

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._items)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self._items

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self._items

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Queue({list(self._items)})"
```

`graph.py` :

```
from queue import Queue


def getNodeName(rootName):
    return input(f"Enter child of node {rootName} : ")


def inputChildren(root):
    print(f"Enter stop to stop entering children for node {root} : ")
    child = list()
    while True:
        data = getNodeName(root)
        if data.lower() == "stop":
            break
        child.append()
    return child


def inputGraph():
    graph = dict()
    queue = Queue()

    queue.enqueue(input("Enter root name : "))

    while len(queue) != 0:
        root = queue.dequeue()
        rootChildren = inputChildren(root)
        queue.extend(rootChildren)

        if len(rootChildren) == 0:
            continue
        else:
            graph[root] = rootChildren

if __name__=="__main__":
    print(inputGraph())
```

Output :

```
Enter root name : A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\graph.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(inputGraph())
  File "D:\graph.py", line 23, in inputGraph
    queue.enqueue(input("Enter root name : "))
  File "D:\queue.py", line 9, in enqueue
    self._items.append(item)
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute '_items'
```

I have tried searching online but cannot figure out why I am getting this error.

Comment: `__int__` should be `__init__`

Comment: `def __int__(self):` You misspelled `__init__`.

Comment: I really don't see why you need Queue class and not use `deque` directly. Or at least inherit from it and implement extra methods/attributes.

Comment: @buran Because I need to use Queue at many places in the code and having a helper class reduces logic duplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import deque


class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._items = deque()

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self._items.append(item)

    def extend(self, *elements):
        self._items.extend(elements)

    def dequeue(self):
        try:
            return self._items.popleft()
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError("Dequeue from empty queue") from Queue

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._items)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self._items

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self._items

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Queue({list(self._items)})"


def getNodeName(rootName):
    return input(f"Enter child of node {rootName} : ")


def inputChildren(root):
    print(f"Enter stop to stop entering children for node {root} : ")
    child = list()
    while True:
        data = getNodeName(root)
        if data.lower() == "stop":
            break
        child.append(data)
    return child


def inputGraph():
    graph = dict()
    queue = Queue()

    queue.enqueue(input("Enter root name : "))

    while len(queue) != 0:
        root = queue.dequeue()
        rootChildren = inputChildren(root)
        queue.extend(rootChildren)

        if len(rootChildren) == 0:
            continue
        else:
            graph[root] = rootChildren

    return graph


if __name__=="__main__":
    print(inputGraph())
```

Comment: 1. In the Queue class, change def __int__(self): to def __init__(self): to fix the misspelling of "init" and properly initialize the Queue object.

2. In the inputChildren function, change child.append() to child.append(data) to append the entered node name to the child list.

3. In the inputGraph function, add a return graph statement at the end to return the constructed graph dictionary.